# set command with no arguments

Tags: bash

I was looking for `env` to display all the environment variables. I happened to issue the command `set` and it seems to "cat" a script to the console. Why does this happen?

This [reference page](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) does not seem to explain it.

```
 If no options or arguments are supplied, set displays the names
 and values of all shell variables
```

Comment: A bunch of lines saying `FOO=bar` is much like a script.

Comment: "If no options or arguments are supplied, set displays the names and values of all shell variables **and functions**"

env would just display environment variables

Comment: Once upon a time `set` did exactly what you wanted. Thanks to all the fancy functions, it's become useless (IMHO). This isn't exactly the same thing, but you might want to just try running `export`, which will probably show the environment variables you're interested in, and doesn't seem to show any function definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank Schrijver explained in his comment, the bash builtin `set` will dump all the shell variables ( variables which only "exist" in that runtime ) and all **shell functions too**, again functions initialised and existing in that particular shell process.
So for example you will see functions like

```
_tilde () 
{ 
   ...
}
```

which is a function whose purpose is provide tab completion on the `~` character for your bash line editor.
Indeed even the bash documentation for `set`, viewable by running the command

```
man bash | less '+/^\s*set \[--'
```

doesn't mention the fact it prints all shell functions by default, but as you have discovered, and others have pointed it - it does print shell functions too.

Answer (score 2):

`set` is a shell builtin command. When you issue that on the command line, you see everything in your current environment. That will include any functions you have loaded. Note that most distros will include at least a few helpful functions in the shell profiles, and if you have bash completion installed, you will have scads of them.

`env` is a binary. It is loaded and executed by the shell, just like any other command. Therefore, it only sees any environment variables that you have exported, which should exclude any functions from your shell environment.